# What does "May your death only ever be written" mean?

Tags: phrases, expressions, sentence-meaning

It was written by a mystery novel writer. She signed this on her book to show appreciation to the detective who solved a real crime and proved that the writer wasn't the murderer.

Answer (score 2):

This statement would be similar in meaning to "May you live forever." Since the writer is an author of murder mysteries, it is a genre-appropriate well-wish to the recipient that she wishes that the only death they would ever experience is the one that is (fictionally) written about them.

Answer (score 0):

This type of phrase can be rewritten as -

> may your death be the only thing that is ever written about you

but since it is to show appreciation, I think @RobJarvis is right about that.